# Error while Publishing files to Azure Web App using FTP

Tags: powershell, azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I am following this [MSDN guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/scripts/app-service-powershell-deploy-ftp) to publish / upload ASP.Net Web Application files to Azure Web App (Resource Manager). But getting UploadFile error whenever the Sub Folder starts. Root folder is going fine.

---

Uploading to ftp://XXXXXX.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/bin/Antlr3.Runtime.dll
From C:\Users\SampleWebApp\bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll

Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s):

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)

---

```
Param(
[string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $AppDirectory, 
[string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $WebAppName, 
[string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $ResourceGroupName 
)

$xml = [Xml](Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -Name $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
-OutputFile null)
$username = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userName").value
$password = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userPWD").value
$url = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@publishUrl").value

Set-Location $appdirectory
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appdirectory -Recurse | Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)}

foreach ($file in $files)
{
if ($file.FullName)
$relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')
$uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")
"Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri
"From " + $file.FullName
$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as the issue starts only with first occurrence of sub directory(bin) file, it could be because of some other process is using the Antlr dll. can you close all active debug sessions and run this script again? and also make sure you're not having any whitespaces after forming relative uri path

**[UPDATE]**
It was failing to create sub-directory and hence the error "file not found" while uploading a file from sub directory.

made few changes in the for-loop to create sub-directory on ftp before uploading file from sub-directory and is working fine.

```
$appdirectory="<Replace with your app directory>"
$webappname="mywebapp$(Get-Random)"
$location="West Europe"

# Create a resource group.
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name myResourceGroup -Location $location

# Create an App Service plan in `Free` tier.
New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name $webappname -Location $location `
-ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Tier Free

# Create a web app.
New-AzureRmWebApp -Name $webappname -Location $location -AppServicePlan $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup

# Get publishing profile for the web app
$xml = (Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -Name $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup `
-OutputFile null)

# Not in Original Script
$xml = [xml]$xml

# Extract connection information from publishing profile
$username = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userName").value
$password = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userPWD").value
$url = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@publishUrl").value

# Upload files recursively 
Set-Location $appdirectory
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appdirectory -Recurse #Removed IsContainer condition
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')  
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")

    if($file.PSIsContainer)
    {
        $uri.AbsolutePath + "is Directory"
        $ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($uri);
        $ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::MakeDirectory
        $ftprequest.UseBinary = $true

        $ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

        $response = $ftprequest.GetResponse();
        $response.StatusDescription
        continue
    }

    "Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri + " from "+ $file.FullName

    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()
```

i also blogged about this in detail on how I troubleshooted this issue to get the fix [here](http://msdevzone.net/2017/07/10/upload-files-to-azure-web-app-via-ftp/#more-251).

Comment: No luck! I tried closing Visual Studio and opened a completely new Instance of Windows Powershell command window. Same result - all the sub-folders are failing.

Comment: I just tried with 2 files 1) In PublishRootFolder - Global.asax  2) In PublishRootFolder\bin - Test.html. I created this structure manually - so there is no chance of some other process holding on to the file. 
                                                                                                         Uploading to ftp://XXXXX.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/bin/Test.html
From C:\PublishPath\bin\Test.html
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable
(e.g., file not found, no access)."

Comment: Please see the update in my answer. it's working - i verified

Comment: Man, You saved my day. Awesome!

Comment: Appreciate you documenting this. Saved me a lot of time.